# How to find and replace {{ }} tags to {!! !!} tags after upgrading a Laravel 4.2 application to 5.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, phpstorm

I have upgraded my application from Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5.0 (the first step on the way to 5.3 :-)

It's quite a lot of work, but one thing causes really headache: I have used `Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider` in the past to generate several HTML tags like forms, formelements and links. For example:

```
{{ Form::label('name', 'Land', array('class' => 'col-md-2 control-label')) }}

{{ HTML::link_to_action('GalleryusersController@index', 'Gallery Users', null, array('class' => 'btn btn-large btn-default btn-block btn-success'))) }}
```

As of Laravel 5.0 these links are escaped and to not render as in the past. In 5.0 one must use `{!! !!}` tags to render these links correctly.

As I do not want to change all `{{ }}` in my application to `{!! !!}` for security reasons, I need a tool for selective searching and replacing recursively in a way, where I can use some kind of variables in the search string and use content of the variables in the replace string: `{{ HTML::<inner part> }}` shall be replaced to `{!! HTML::<inner part> !!}`.

I tried to use PhpStorm's "Replace Structurally" function, but I didn't get it to work as needed. I am not sure, if this tool can do what I want.

**Question:**
Can anybody help me to get this PhpStorm function to work? Or has anybody another idea how to easily achieve my goal?

**Update 1**
As Andy mentioned, in version 5.3 the behaviour is like in 4.2 and I can use `{{ }}` again to create my links and forms :-) I also found out in my test environments, that the behaviour changed in version 5.2.

Allthough I hope that anybody knows a solution for my search and replace question as maybe once I need this for something else. Any suggestions will be appriciated!

Comment: FYI, I'm using 5.3 and Laravel Collective's Form/HTML composer package and I set up my `Form` and `Html` blocks up like `{{ Form::open` and they work fine

Comment: Thanks Andy for the hint! I installed test environments to verify that and found out that the behaviour changed from version 5.1 to 5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this replacement with PhpStorm using `Replace in Path...` dialog `(Ctrl+Shift+R)`, checking Regular Expression and employing this expressions:

Text fo find: `\{\{ Form::(.+?)\}\}`

Replace with: `\{!! Form::$1!!\}`

And so on with `HTML::`

Comment: Thank you very much! That works like charm :-) For those who use a Mac: The shortcut is ´Shift+Cmd+R`.